# Angular2 RxJS stream call HTTP for each child of parent collection

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a component that calls http to get a collection of objects (users).  For each of those users I need to make another separate http call to get some additional details of the users.  How do I do this with RxJS and observables?  Behavior shown in this plunk where we get a list of github users and then try to retrieve each of their followers to get a follower count.

The subscription code is in user-grid.component.ts.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xuu5jqeKVmbY5qwHLJJt

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.users$ = this._githubUserService.getUsers()
        .map((res) => res.json())
        .flatMap((users) => Observable.from(users))
        .flatMap((e) => {
          return this._githubUserService.getFollowers(e.followers_url)
          .map((followers)=> followers.json())
         }, (e, res) => e.followers = res)     
}
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `return` in your second `flatMap`.

Comment: fixed the return which resolved the error, but still not getting the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not terribly familiar with the async pipe, but it seems that your problem is that the `*ngFor` treats each new value from the `Observable` as a rehydration of the list. The second function that you are passing to the `flatMap` is returning the array that is returned from the followers call (which is incidentally why it also seems to flicker, because each time a new request resolves it rebuilds the list).

I think if you append the `toArray` operator to the end that will wait until all the values have returned.

Further, since you are resolving the `followers` into an Array you don't need to use the async pipe on the nested h4.

See here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X2OjHGiPpmml2cmLD1tm?p=preview

The interesting bits:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray';


ngOnInit(){
    this.users$ = this._githubUserService.getUsers()
        .map((res) => res.json())
        .flatMap(users => users)
        .flatMap(
          (e) => this._githubUserService.getFollowers(e.followers_url), 
          (e, res) => Object.assign(e, {followers: res.json()}))
        .toArray();
}

// in user-grid.component.html
<md-list>
  <h1 md-header>GitHub Users</h1>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
    <a href="https://github.com/{{user.login}}" target="_new">
      <img md-list-avatar [src]="user.avatar_url">
    </a>
    <h4>{{user.login}} (followers: {{user.followers.length}})</h4>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what the .flatMap(users => users) does for us?  Does it take an collection and convert it to a single object where each item in the collection is a node?  Curious why this is necessary before the second flatMap.  This solution works and is very readable, thank you!

Comment: Exactly. The `flatMap` flattens out the users array. Without it your second flatMap would receive an array of users instead of an individual user. Normally it would be for flattening an `Observable` but it can implicitly handle iterable types like `Arrays` and `Promises`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to open your plnkr (it's returning me 403 - Forbidden), but I think that if you want to build a structure like this:

`[{ userId: 1, followersQtt : 25 }, { userId: 2, followersQtt : 18 }, ... ]`

You could do something like this:

```
//get the users' json as an Array
let usersJsonArray = this._githubUserService.getUsers().map((res) => res.json()); 

this.users$ = Observable.from(usersJsonArray) //we have to convert the Array to an Observable               
                .flatMap((user) => {

                    //get the followers' json
                    let followersJsonArray = this._githubUserService.getFollowers(user.followers_url).map((res) => res.json());

                    return Observable.from(followersJsonArray) //again, we have to convert the Array to an Observable                               
                                .map(() => 1) //map each follower to the number 1
                                .reduce((x,y) => x+y) //sums up all the followers (that were mapped to the number '1')
                                .map((followersQtt) => { userId : user.id, followersQtt : followersQtt }) //return an object with the informations (I don't know if the user's id is really in the property user.id)    

                });
```

Comment: .map((users) => Observable.from(users)) , should we use flatmap here ?

Comment: At this moment I'm expecting it to be an `Array` and not an `Observable`, so there would be no `flatMap` function.. but now thinking, that might be the problem, we're not converting the Array to an Observable.. I'm updating my answer